# What's the relationship between domain and the degree of a polynomial?

Tags: ring-theory

> Since d(x)|2, and since Z[x] is a domain, the degree of d(x) cannot
>   exceed that of 2.
>
> (Provided d(x) ∈ Z[x])

Why d(x) | 2 and Z[x] is a domain implies that the degree of d(x) cannot exceed 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misread the English: it is saying

> The degree of $d(x)$ cannot exceed the degree of $2$.

Maybe it helps to rename things. If we define $f$ to be the polynomial $f(x) = 2$, then the quoted passage intends to say

> The degree of $d(x)$ cannot exceed the degree of $f(x)$.

Comment: If we define f(x)=2, then is it a constant polynomial. Then deg(f(x)) should be 0. I'm confused.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: But I still don't understand why deg(d(x))<2

Comment: It's not saying deg(d(x))<2.  It's saying deg(d(x))<deg(2).

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!! I get it. What an awkward...

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with polynomials over a ring that admits zero divisors, then it is not always true that $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$.  For instance, if the coefficient ring is $\mathbb Z_4$, then $(2x+1)(2x+1) = 1$.

But if there are no zero-divisors in the coefficient ring (i.e. it is a domain), then the highest-degree term of the product will always come from the highest-degree terms of the factors.

This is why it makes sense to mention that $\mathbb Z$ is a domain before concluding that the degree of a polynomial does not exceed the degree of a multiple of that polynomial.

Comment: It seems we don't know about the highest-degree. I think d(x)|2 only tells us that the coefficients of d(x) are even. So how can we conclude that deg(d(x)) < 2?

Comment: d(x) | 2 does not tell us that the coefficients are even;  that would follow from 2 | d(x), which is completely different.

Comment: @user8314628 The degree of $2$ is zero, so the degree of any polynomial dividing $2$ is $\le0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $R$ is a domain, then for any two poynomials $f,g \in R[x]$, it is true that

$$f | g \implies \deg(f) \le \deg(g)$$

The statement you are asking about is just the special case of this in which $g$ is the constant polynomial $g=2$.  It asserts that
$$f| 2 \implies \deg(f) \le \deg(2)$$
(The phrase "less than that of 2" is a shorter way of saying "less than the degree of the polynomial 2".)  In particular, the sentence is *not* saying that $\deg(f) \le 2$; in fact it's saying something quite a bit stronger than that, namely that $\deg(f) = 0$, i.e. $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Yea, I got it. Thank you!